# How to execute lynx -dump

Tags: c++, lynx

This may sound stupid, but is there a way to open terminal and execute "lynx -dump HTML.html > text.txt" using C++?

Comment: Why do you want to open a terminal for that? It should work without, simply calling `system`. (Oh, and what kind of operating system are you using?)

Comment: It works! 

With little help from here, I manage to do:

    system("lynx -dump http://google.com > file.txt");

I am using Linux. =)

Comment: Accepted. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use system() function. See here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/system